# MS ACcess to SQL Server Where Clause conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a where clause in an OLD msaccess query which I am converting to SQL Server.  Just trying to get some input on this.

The where clause in this Access Query is not valid for SQL Server.

Here is the Access Where statement...

```
WHERE (((MyTable.MYField) <> IsNull([MYField])))
```

Does anyone have a good replacement for this...  MyTable.MYField is an integer value and Isnull in MS Access returns a boolean true or false value but this syntax is incorrect for SQL Server and I have tried a few permutations of this to no avail.  Sorry can't provide data or real field names....

I understand about linking the tables and what not but with millions of rows that is not a good solution...

Any Takers on this?

Comment: What have you tried in SQL Server that didn't work?

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE MyField IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I feel quite expert on ms access, but frankly that where clause does not make any sense to me. What is it trying to filter ??

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the intent of your original query correctly as you're trying to filter out records where MyField has a NULL value, you need to use the IS NOT NULL construct.

`WHERE MyTable.MyField IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

That is a very weird looking `where` clause. I was curious, so did some investigation ... the TLDR conclusion of which is that the clause is equivalent to:

`where MyField <> 0`

I created the following table in MS Access 2013:

```
TestTable
---------
ID autonumber,
MyField number
```

And populated it as follows

```
ID | MyField
------------
1  | -1
2  | 0
3  | 1
4  | NULL
```

I then wrote the following query,

```
SELECT
    TestTable.ID,
    TestTable.MyField,
    TestTable.MyField AS MyFieldAsTrueFalse,
    IsNull([MyField]) AS IsNullAsTrueFalse,
    IsNull([MyField]) AS IsNullAsInt
FROM
    TestTable;
```

The last three fields where "formatted" as their aliases suggest using the "properties" in the design view of the query. This returns the following dataset:

```
ID | MyField | MyFieldAsTrueFalse | IsNullAsTrueFalse | IsNullAsInt
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | -1      | TRUE               | FALSE             | 0
2  | 0       | FALSE              | FALSE             | 0
3  | 1       | TRUE               | FALSE             | 0
4  | NULL    | NULL               | TRUE              | -1
```

After adding the provided where clause (`TestTable.MyField<>IsNull([MyField])`) to the query, I then only see the rows with IDs 1 and 3.

So, I think what MS Access is doing is converting the numeric field in MyField to a boolean. The way it does that is that anything other than zero becomes `TRUE`. `NULL`, however, remains `NULL`. So when evaluating the where clause it's doing the following:

### LHS: MyField [as TRUE/FALSE/NULL]

Pseudo code

```
case
    when MyField is NULL then NULL
    when MyField = 0 then FALSE
    else TRUE
end
```

### RHS: isnull(MyField) [as TRUE/FALSE]

Pseudo code

```
case
    when MyField is NULL then TRUE
    else FALSE
end
```

If you follow this through, I reckon the where clause is therefore equivalent to:

```
where MyField <> 0
```

This will filter out nulls and zeroes, gives the same results in MS Access and will obviously convert to SQL-Server without complaint.